# UITests all failing, but not when run separately

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I have written 5 UITests that each interact with different parts in the app. 3 of them tap a `UIButton` in the section header of a `UITableView`. The first taps the first section's header, the second the second and so on. When I run these separately, they pass. When I run all tests, they fail.

```
- (void)testFirst {
    XCUIElement *table = self.app.tables.allElementsBoundByIndex[0];
    [[[self.app.tables.otherElements containingType:XCUIElementTypeStaticText identifier:@"Table"] childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeButton].element tap];

    sleep(3);

    XCUIElement *titleField = self.app.textFields[@"Name"];
    [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = @"testName";
    [titleField doubleTap];
    [self.app.menuItems[@"Paste"] tap];
}

- (void)testSecond {
    XCUIElement *table = self.app.tables.allElementsBoundByIndex[0];
    [[[self.app.tables.otherElements containingType:XCUIElementTypeStaticText identifier:@"Chair"] childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeButton].element tap];

    sleep(3);

    XCUIElement *titleField = self.app.textFields[@"Name"];
    [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = @"testName";
    [titleField doubleTap];
    [self.app.menuItems[@"Paste"] tap];
}

- (void)testThird {
    XCUIElement *table = self.app.tables.allElementsBoundByIndex[0];
    [[[self.app.tables.otherElements containingType:XCUIElementTypeStaticText identifier:@"Guy"] childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeButton].element tap];

    sleep(3);

    XCUIElement *titleField = self.app.textFields[@"Name"];
    [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = @"testName";
    [titleField doubleTap];
    [self.app.menuItems[@"Paste"] tap];
}
```

As I said, when I run one of these seperately, they pass. But when I run them all, 2 or all 3 of them will fail on `[self.app.menuItems[@"Paste"] tap];` or `[titleField doubleTap];`. I've been busting my head on this for hours. Any ideas as to what's causing this?

EDIT: I added my `setUp` and `tearDown` methods.

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

    // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
    self.continueAfterFailure = NO;
    // UI tests must launch the application that they test. Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.

    // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.

    self.app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];

    self.snapshot = [[SnapshotHelper alloc] init];
    [self.snapshot setupSnapshot:self.app];

    [self.app launch];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    [super tearDown];
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented `setUp` and `tearDown` for your tests? It seems like you aren't resetting state between the tests

Comment: @bplattenburg I added them to the question, but I don't see what I should be tearing down. Any ideas?